# npm run build > not creating dist folder in NestJs project

Tags: json, nestjs

I tried to start my project with `npm run start:prod` command but got

**`Error: Cannot find module {path to my project}\dist\main.js'`.**

I have tried to rename the path to all my files in the project from src/myController to ../myController .

**My package.json (scripts)**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon\" \"tsc -w -p tsconfig.json\" ",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && npm run build",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js"
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": [ "./src/**/*.ts", ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/__test__/*"]
}
```

**The actual output:**

> nest-typescript-starter@1.0.0 prestart:prod 
>   {path to my project}
>   rimraf dist && npm run build
>
> nest-typescript-starter@1.0.0 build 
>   {path to my project}
>   tsc -p tsconfig.build.json
>
> nest-typescript-starter@1.0.0 start:prod 
>   {path to my project}
>   node dist/main.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

> Error: Cannot find module
>   {path to my project}\dist\main.js'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okeey, I was a little dumb. The answer is very easy. In package.json you need change line from `"start:prod": "node dist/main.js"` to `"start:prod": "node dist/src/main.js"`. In  tsconfig.json you need change `"outDir": "../dist"` to `"outDir": "./dist"`

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the correct solution, by the way, to help others in the future know what response to look at.

Comment: This helped me as well. I believe in my case its due to a fact I'm generating typings from schema outside of the `src`. Still I don't like much seeing `dist/src` at all yet that's another story...

Comment: I had the same problem, it looks like NestJs ships with the following in the package.json

`"start:prod": "node dist/main"` updating to `"start:prod": "node dist/src/main"` solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

you can just add a new command:
under the scripts in package.json :

```
"start:live": "rimraf dist && nest build && node dist/src/main",
```

then you can run:

```
npm run start:live
```

Comment: Consider formatting your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting it makes it better readable